# pixel level multiclass segmentation, issues about training all zero pixel images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to implement a multiclass semantic segmentation model with 5 different classes.
some of the images have all 5 class ground truth masks, some are not. For example, the image below has all 5 different-class ground truth masks. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFm6T.png)

My question is, what if I had this image like below to be trained but has no classes in the image. Should I still train this image with 5 channel filled with all zeros?
Does it train the model efficiently, making it reduces false positives?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIc2e.png)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is good.

It is likely that your model will reduce the false positives if you train with all your data; at the same time it may also increase the number of false negatives, as it will be less certain about the important class your want to predict in your CT-scans.

In order to test your assumptions, you must train the same neural network with two different datasets:

1. One with all the data. Here the imbalance will be much greater. In the end, every medical segmentation problem is by definition highly imbalanced, the more if you have masks with no classes of interest marked. In your case, it is even more imbalanced: depending on the nature of your problem, there can be imbalance even between your 5 classes together with the background/classes of interest one.
2. One with data where masks are marked with the class you are trying to predict.

Then, test these models on your test set, and see which one does better with FP/FN.

Comment: @user12922441, since you accepted my answer as solving one,  please also upvote it(upper triangle)